# What is the VS command to show Intellisense errors?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, vsvim

In Visual Studio, code that has an error is marked with red squiggles.
If I hover the mouse cursor over the text, VS displays a popup with the details of the error.
I would like to do the same from the keyboard, by using a keybinding. In order to do that I need to find the name of the command.

I've tried a number of the commands that seems related (like Edit.QuickInfo) from this [list](https://github.com/aburok/mysettings/blob/master/VisualStudio/vscommands.txt). But without success so far.

Thanks,
Julien

Comment: Note: I confirmed with the VS team that there is indeed a bug here. QuickInfo should show the contents of the error but currently it only does so if it has some other information about the current selection that it could display.
Track the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10661

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor on code where the red squiggles are and use `Ctrl+.` to show up suggestion for error correction/code manipulation, it also shows the error message. In case it is not showing message then selecting any suggestion using down arrow key will show the error message.

Comment: That did not work.  
For example, if I mistype the word `static`, then move my cursor to that squiggled word and press `Ctrl+.`, the status line simply says "No quick actions available here" and there are no suggestions or error message displayed.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+K`, `Ctrl+I` simulates the hovering under the cursor.